# How to convert List elements into separate data.frames?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, xlsx

I have loaded an Excel.xlsx which has 8 sheets as a list, by

```
> require (XLConnect)
> wb <- loadWorkbook ("D:/data /Excel.xlsx")    
> list <- readWorksheet (wb, sheet = getSheets (wb))
```

But what I want to get are 8 independent data.frames. So I want to "unlist" the list into data.frames. I've tried ldply, but this combine all the 8 sheets into one data.frame.

Does anyone know how to load sheets under one Excel to be separate data.frames? Or how to convert List elements into separate data.frames? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you check `?list2env`?

Comment: ah...I don't know. Can you be more specific about how to use list2env?

Comment: What difference does it make whether they are stored in separate variables or together in a list? The single list is actually _more_ flexible.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But I want to join some sheets into one, and then join this one with some other sheets. How to do this when the sheets are stored in the list? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by join, which seems like the sort of detail and clarification that should have been in your question in the first place. `do.call(rbind,list(...))`? Or maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8091303/324364)?

Comment: `list2env(list, .GlobalEnv)` will create a data frame for every object you have in `list` (note that the objects have to have names). But you should listen to @joran first (he has a Mac :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook ("D:/data /Excel.xlsx") 
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
invisible(lapply(sheets,function(sheet) 
             assign(sheet,readWorksheet (wb, sheet = sheet ),pos=1)))
```

This will create data frames for each sheet, named as the sheet names.

*However*: this business of using `assign(...)` to create variables silently is generally frowned upon.

Comment: This works perfectly! Love it love it!!